# import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages'

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, mean-stack

I'm just learning. I ran into this problem when I installed the Angular 2 flash messages module in my project. The installation was not successful.

`npm i angular2-flash-messages`

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: front-end@0.0.0 npm ERR!
> Found: @angular/core@14.0.0 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core npm
> ERR!   @angular/core@"^14.0.0" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^6.0.0"
> from angular2-flash-messages@3.0.1 npm ERR!
> node_modules/angular2-flash-messages npm ERR!
> angular2-flash-messages@"*" from the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command
> with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect
> (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR!  npm ERR! See
> C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full
> report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Who faced this. please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a versioning problem. angular2-flash-messages is still using Angular-Core 6.0.0 and you are using Angular-core 14 going on the error message.

Probably there are a few breaking changes between these versions.

I checked angular2-flash-messages and they did not publish a new package for over 4 years, so my advise would be to pick some other package that does the same.

You could also downgrade your Angular, you could try version 12, 8 (before Ivy), or 6, but I would not advise this because then you are stuck on that version only for this package.

Yet another option is to update the package to a newer version yourself:
https://github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages

Comment: What is the best version to change to?

Comment: As mentioned in the post You could also downgrade your Angular, you could try version 12, 8 (before Ivy), or 6, but I would not advise this because then you are stuck on that version only for this package. If you want to be sure the package works you can go for Angular 6, that is the one used by the package. But downgrading your Angular app will be a pain in the b

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem today.
The problem occured when using angular 12 with "@angular/fire": "7.2.1", and
"firebase": "9.6.7"

The problems solved when I did this:

1. go to package.json, I added ^ (carret) to these packages: "@angular/fire": "^7.2.1" and "firebase": "^9.6.7"
2. then I deleted node_modules folder entirely
3. run: npm install
4. the problem solved

note: Why I added ^ ? Because, I saw the warning, the red line was occured in those particular packages, so I guess something in those packages and voile. It worked.